# register click on everything on body except div and all its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to hide some `li` elements when any element on the page is clicked that isn't them or their container (`div.dropdown_container`). I can't seem to get it to work though.

```
  $("body").on("click", "*:not(div.dropdown_container, div.dropdown_container > *)", function(e){
    // don't want to hide the very first `li`
    // it contains a span i want always to show
    $("ul.dropdown_ul > li:not(#first)").hide();
  });
```

[JSBIN - very last function on the page](http://jsbin.com/iwicud/13/edit)

How can I change this so that everything gets this listener but not the div.dropdown_container or any child element within it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do.

`e.target` gets you the element that was clicked.

So this checks if the click was generated on the div itself or any of it's children.

```
 $("body").on("click",function(e) {

      if( $(e.target).is('div.dropdown_container') 
             || $(e.target).closest('div.dropdown_container').length) {
            // do something
      }
      else {
         // do something else
      }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you. `if ($(e.target).is('div.dropdown_container') || $(e.target).closest('div.dropdown_container').length) {console.log("A");}else {console.log("B");}});` always logs `"A"` for me though.

Comment: Can you create a sample fiddle

Comment: http://jsbin.com/iwicud/16/edit clicking on one of the text inputs logs "B" actually, I was mistaken. But clicking elsewhere on the body does not.

Comment: I see. it's because I was clicking at the same altitude as the `div.dropdown_container` and its width was being set at 100% so it was still "getting clicked". Is there a way to set its width to be no more than its children? Thanks so much.

Comment: Yup.. you can do that or set `display:inline-block `

Comment: This didn't work for me until I moved my code inside the else brackets. I wonder what is the opposite of the if statement because $(e.target).not('div.dropdown_container') is not not enough. Thanks for a great answer anyway.

Comment: @usefulBee . Any element on the body that is not the container will fall into the else block.